# watchdog node in OMNET++ for simulating a MANET model

Tags: omnet++, intrusion-detection

I'm trying to make a MANET model in OMNET++ for that i need to make a watchdog node. I'm just wondering if anyone have the code for the watchdog node.

Comment: Could you give us a bit more detail? SO works best when you are able to give a direct example of what you are working with.

Comment: There are already  existing mobile adhoc network models in NS2. so i want to simulate a simple MANET model in OMNET++. where there are transactions of Data Packs and ACK packs among nodes and the watchdog node watches over the nodes and checks if there are any misbehaving nodes in the network.